# Не работает горячая клавиша F7 (переход в режим конструктора)

Tags: visual-studio-2017

В параметрах ничего не изменилось, все по-прежнему четко прописано, как всегда: F7 везде должно работать как переход к конструктору и обратно к коду, что в Win Forms, что в XAML, нажимаю в главном меню -> вид - напротив слова "конструктор" не обозначено никаких клавиш(как и напротив слова "код", соответственно и не действуют и сами клавиши! после обновления VS 15.1.
Как избавиться от этого интеллектуального кошмара?

Comment: Проверено дополнительно на ноутбуке, та же версия VS, так же не работает переход из конструктора в код и обратно через горячие клавиши